# Show or Hide element or Style element by using ref or nativeID

Tags: react-native

How can I use the refText to update the element '**Text**'

```
const refText = null;
const doSomething = () =>{
    refText.changeVisibility("hidden"); // something like that
}
return <Text ref={refText} onPress={doSomething}>Some Text</Text>;
```

I tried to find any way to work with it, but can't find any solution over google. Or maybe I missed.

Answer (score 1):

[`setNativeProps`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation) may be what you're looking for, however this is generally not the recommended way to make updates to an element. Instead, consider using state and updating relevant props/styles of your component in response to that state change:

[Example on Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@levibuzolic/chunky-cashew)

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Toggle" onPress={() => setVisible(previous => !previous)} />
      {visible && (
        <Text onPress={() => setVisible(false)} style={{padding: 20}}>Click this text to hide it</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```